# Solaris11 packaging

Tags: solaris

I am just started exploring the Solaris kernel. I am studying the Solaris kernel modules. During my study I got following question, Is it possible to embed two kernel modules (e.g Solaris 11 and Solaris 11.4 kernel modules) in single package? This scenario is doable in Linux but not sure it is possible in Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to embed two modules (say `/kernel/misc/foo` and `/kernel/drv/bar`) in the same Solaris IPS package, but not two versions of the same module for different OS releases (such as `/kernel/drv/bar` for 11.3 and `/kernel/drv/bar` for 11.4).   That problem is usually solved by making two versions of the package - one for the older release and one for the newer release, during the transition period (such as right now, since Solaris 11.4 just came out, so not everyone has upgraded from 11.3 yet - Solaris 11.0 through 11.2 are no longer supported, so you shouldn't need to build modules for them).